# How to create an topic menu with Jekyll / Liquid

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to create an outline to simulate a menu with direct link to the post.
This structure would be similar to the help manuals for topics or as the structure of chapters of books.

The problem is how to do, I thought of creating the structure in config.yml defining a tag and a title for each topic and checking recursively if there is a sub-topic. I do not think that is the most correct way, but I generated such a structure:

http://pastebin.com/k07yPmAq

As I would travel this array, printing the titles and the corresponding posts these tags?

Or is there better way?

Obs .: This will be on GitHub, so I can not use plugins.

Comment: Are you a german dude that lives in brazil :D?

Comment: No, my grandparents are German and came to Brazil. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use plugins the only way, that I know, to achieve this is to loop through the list, one loop for each level. Here is an example:

```
<ul class="topics">
{% for topic in site.topics %}
    <li>
        <a title="{{topic.title}}" href="/tags/{{topic.tag}}">{{topic.title}}</a>
        {% if topic.subtopics %}
        <ul class="subtopics">
            {% for subtopic in topic.subtopics %}
                <li>
                    <a title="{{subtopic.title}}" href="/tags/{{subtopic.tag}}">{{subtopic.title}}</a>
                   <!-- add another for if you have another level, and so on... -->
                </li>
            {% endfor %} 
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %} 
<ul>
```

I don't think that you should be afraid by performance, since here you're compiling one time "slow", to serve many times "fast".

**P.s.**
If you don't need to generate the menu from the config file, you could always write it directly in html, inside a file, e.g. `_includes/navigation.html` and then include it from layouts using `{% include navigation.html %}`.

Comment: I have decided to use this solution, ty. :)